# onMouseLeave trigger alert twice even with stopPropagation

Tags: alert, stoppropagation

```
$('.pool').on('mouseleave', function (e) {                
            var el = $(this).find('.pool-row').find('input[type=submit]');

            if (el.length)
                alert('bla bla bla');

            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return;
        });
```

The alert is triggering twice on mouseleave even with stopPropagation or preventDefault and "return;".

[SOLVED]
The second alert was being triggered because there was another mouseleave event on a parent element, and the alert() triggered a 'mouseleave'.

Comment: You should stop the propagation before calling the alert, it is better to move`e.stopPropagation()` to the first line of your callback function.

Comment: I've try it, but still triggering twice on mouseLeave...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some quick modifications on your script, and it seems that it does not trigger the alert twice!

```js
$('.pool').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  var el = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]')

  if (el.length)
      alert('bla bla bla')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pool">
  <p>This is a pool</p>
  
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: It helped me to understand the problem. Thanks!!